# Did Agni refuse to burn Sati at the Daksha Yagna?

Tags: agni, sati-goddess

Devdutt Pattanaik says this in one of his talks - when Agni wouldn't burn her, Sati burnt herself with her own internal fire, according to him.  Is there scriptural basis for this?

Answer (score 1):

The works of Devdutt Pattanaik are not reliable, as they paint the characters from Hindu literature in a wrong manner.

[Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226049.html) says that angered with her father Daksha's behaviour towards Shiva, Sati decides to cast off her body, as she was born to Daksha.

> 59. Fie upon Him who is always wicked and who perpetrates actions of unspeakable demerit. Sensible man should shun even the contact with
>       such a man.
> 60. **I am the offspring of your race** as the bull-bannered lord Śiva has often said. Hence naturally my name has come to be Dākṣāyaṇī. This
>       is distressing to me.
> 61. ***This body born of your limbs I shall cast off as a corpse***. It is worthy of contempt. I shall abandon it and gain happiness.

Later she sats in Yogic posture, meditating on Shiva, [reduces her body to ashes](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226050.html).

> 8. Her body divested of its sins fell in the yogic fire and ***was reduced to ashes***, O excellent sage, in accordance with her own wish.

There was no mention of Agni refusing to burn her, in this chapter.